# How to use Activation Functions in Quantized Nerual Networks?

Tags: neural-networks, tensorflow

I want to understand how quantized networks can calculate activations like sigmoid and tanh. I stumbled over [this question](http://www.immobilienscout24.de/expose/140187433) which mentions the implementation of TF-Lite Micro as an example. Specifically, the implementation of the tanh function in [internal/reference/integer_ops/tanh.h lines 62 and 94](https://github.com/tensorflow/tflite-micro/blob/main/tensorflow/lite/kernels/internal/reference/integer_ops/tanh.h).

I can see that a LUT based implementation using interpolation is used. However, I don't understand where the parameters `input_multiplier` and `input_left_shift` come from. Besides, I want to understand what exactly the bit shift operations are used for here. Is there some additional information on this available? I couldn't find any more in-depth information regarding quantization and activation functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no accepted generic approach. Essentially, underlying activation function is re-implemented with a smaller precision i.e., arithmetic operations and operands that represents the activation function.

Probably, bitshift operations mimics the internal results of operators.

See also, [QPyTorch: A Low-Precision Arithmetic Simulation Framework](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/9463516).

Comment: If there is no generic approach, is there at least some documentation on how it can be done for one specific case? There is the TFMicro implementation I posted, but I am more interested in an explanation of the design process, which is lacking here as it is just the code itself.

Comment: QPyTorch paper explains the design process. Rather than specific case, design implements different quantisation strategies and converts full precision objects, see [functionality overview](https://github.com/Tiiiger/QPyTorch/blob/master/examples/tutorial/Functionality_Overview.ipynb).